# Prevent div click from raising a server event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

The div is used like an Image button. Based on the selected value of the drop down, it does some work.
When the value of DropDown is 1, the div click should not trigger. No matter what the value is, the div click is hitting the C# code. What should I do , so that it hits only when the value is > 1.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
 <ContentTemplate>
  <div id="divFirst" runat="server" class="first" 
   onclick="return ShowPage('first')"></div>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**JS:**

```
function ShowPage(page) {
            var n = parseInt($("#ddl").val());                

            switch (page) {
                case 'first':
                    if (n > 1)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                    break;
           }
        }
```

**C#:**

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent(string EventArg)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EventArg))
            {
                switch(EventArg)
                {
                    case "divFirst_Click":
                        divFirst_Click();
                        break;                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried preventDefault() in ShowPage function?

Comment: `else
                        $("#divFirst").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });` This didn't work..

Comment: $("#divFirst"), i think that id will be another, try to use divFirst.ClientID: $("#<%=divFirst.ClientID%>").click(....);